# Issue Installing SSMS V17.0

Tags: sql-server, ssms

When I try to install SQL Server Management Studio, Version 17.0, I receive the following error message:

> "The Generally Available (GA) version of SQL Server Management Studio
>   (SSMS) v17.0 cannot be installed because a pre-release version of SSMS
>   is installed on your computer. Uninstall the pre-release version of
>   SSMS from 'Add/Remove Programs' in the Control Panel and run SSMS
>   setup again."

I uninstalled the pre-release version, but still have the issue. When I look at the log file, the condition that is causing the problem is

> [1118:18D4][2017-05-09T16:05:55]i052: Condition 'NOT RCBitsInstalled
>   OR (RCBitsInstalled > "2016.140.17030.0" OR RCBitsInstalled <
>   "2016.140.0.0")' evaluates to false.

But looking into the log file further, that value seems fine.

> [1118:18D4][2017-05-09T16:05:55]i000: Setting version variable
>   'RCBitsInstalled' to value '2016.140.16000.64'

Anyone know a way around this? Thanks!

Comment: I removed the sql-server-2017 tag simply because Microsoft has actively and explicitly separated SSMS from the engine, so the version of an engine isn't relevant when talking about an SSMS issue. I'm not sure if we need to add tags to segregate issues with a specific version of SSMS, or if we can relegate that to the content of the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Delete the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\ and then try the installer again. You may need to reboot to release all file handles.

[image]

Comment: Winner winner, chicken dinner. Removing it via add/remove programs still left all the files there, strange enough.